Homotopy type of wedge of spheres via cohomology
It is known to me that given a simply connected finite dimensional which is also level-wise finite CW-complex $X$ such that $\tilde{H}_k(X,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}^m$ and all other homologies with integer coefficient vanishes, then $X$ is homotopic to wedge of $m$ many spheres of dimension $k$ due to the fact that Moore spaces are unique up to homotopy.
If the same data is given in terms of cohomology the same result holds due to universal coefficient theorem. (I just check it in MO! in the following link).
My question is as follows.

Can I say if $X$ is a simply connected finite dimensional CW-complex with $H^0(X,\mathbb{Z})=0, H^k(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is direct sum of countable copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ and all other $H^i(X,\mathbb{Z})=0$ then $X$ is homotopic to wedge of spheres of dimension $k$?

Thanks in advance!!

This should be impossible by the universal coefficients theorem.
